# hover becomes unactive when used together with auto margins

Tags: css, button, hover, aptana

I have a problem and I don't know what's the reason of it. I've made a simple layout that includes two buttons and I wanted them to change their appearence whenever I hover the cursor over them. The problem is that I tested it in [codepen](http://codepen.io/DjAndrew89/pen/Jqzue) and it works, but when I use it in aptana (I wrote the code in there), and try to see the result, the second button simply doesn't change it's state on hover, even if both the buttons have almost the same attributes. If I delete the margin:0 auto; it works in aptana too, but it modifies the button position, and I don't want that.

```
<div id="slides">
<div id="button">PORTFOLIO</div>
<div id="button_second">SERVICES</div>
</div>

#slides{
width:1366px;
height:300px;
position:relative;
}
#button{
width:150px;
height:35px;
background:#f88560;
color:#ffebc9;
border-radius:7px;
margin:0 auto;
line-height:35px;
text-align: center;
position:absolute;
top:130px;
left:0;
right:0;
font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
}
#button:hover{
background:#faa387;
color:#FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer; 
}
#button_second{
width:85px;
height:25px;
background:#3899db;
color:#FFFFFF;
border-radius:7px;
margin:0 auto;
line-height:25px;
text-align: center;
position:absolute;
top:287px;
left:0;
right:0;
font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
}
#button_second:hover{
background:#faa387;
color:#FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer; 
}
```

Comment: May I recommend that you add a class to each button and use that to ad your styles? It will be much less code and will likely save you some headaches. The only thing you would want to keep in your id's though would be your specific positioning for the element, although I would highly recommend you avoid positioning whenever you can. It often causes more work then necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use classes in your css to help keep common code together. For insistence if your buttons all use the same font then you can put that font on a class or if they are the same width ect.

Also, try to use positioning as a last resort. If you are just adding spacing please use `margins` or `padding` to accomplish what you need it to look like. Positioning often causes more problems for you down the road.

Here is a fiddle with an example of your code.
http://jsfiddle.net/3F4cS/